# How to share app settings between multiple Azure websites

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an application which has multiple websites, one for each logical function:

- User-facing
- Back end - receives web hooks etc
- Other

The sites have a bunch of configuration info. appsettings variables and connection strings in common. Regardless of how I do configuration management, eg via the Azure Portal or scripted via Powershell I want to do as little repeat as possible to keep things simple and reduce opportunity for errors when deploying/ managing these configuration settings.

What recommendations are there for managing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend deploying the various sites using [ARM Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/). You can then use the same deployment parameters for multiple sites to end up with each having the same app settings.

As an aside, please note that deployment slots do **not** share app settings. You have to apply them to each slot. So it's probably not a good candidate for your needs.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer.  You've helped me understand that my understanding of how appsettings relate to slots was totally wrong.  Now I understand it - as you said, the appsettings aren't shared by the slots, they simply move with instance of the website when slots are swapped, and the "slot setting" checkbox binds a particular setting to it's given slot.